# How I create a dynamic Pop up in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, popup, controls

I had wrote a ASP.NET Application that show User Informations from a Active Directory. I use two WebForms. In My first WinForm I can list all User in the AD or search a User. With a Button I can see more Informations about the selected User in the second WinForm. Now I don't want see the main Informations about the selected User in the second WinForm but in a kind of a Pop Up. This Popup is not fix on the desktop but selected.

for example:

[image]

How I can create this and what is that for a Control? Any Helplinks would help me :P

tarasov

Comment: Have a look here http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: hello see this url http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12037/A-Custom-Dialog-Box-Control

Comment: can I set Buttons on this, too?